# Is it possible to coerce string values in xml to bool?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, coercion

Let's suppose I have xml like this one:

```
<Server Active="No">
    <Url>http://some.url</Url>
</Server>
```

C# class looks like this:

```
public class Server
{
   [XmlAttribute()]
   public string Active { get; set; }

   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to change Active property to type `bool` and have XmlSerializer coerce "Yes" "No" to bool values?

**Edit**: Xml is received, I cannot change it. So, in fact, i'm interested in deserialization only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might look at a second property:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool Active { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("Active"), Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public string ActiveString {
    get { return Active ? "Yes" : "No"; }
    set {
        switch(value) {
            case "Yes": Active = true; break;
            case "No": Active = false; break;
            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty neat way to do it. My only complaint is that ActiveString will be visible in IntelliSense within same project.

Comment: @Kugel - within the *same* project, yes. The `[EditorBrowsable(...)]` at least tries to deal with *other* projects, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and you will have control over how the xml is serialized and deserialized

Comment: However, in the general case (if we assume there are nested objects etc) that is a pretty horrible interface to have to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Server
{
   [XmlAttribute()]
   public bool Active { get; set; }

   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

The previous class should end up in that serialized form :

```
<Server Active="false">
    <Url>http://some.url</Url>
</Server>
```

Comment: ...which doesn't really match what the OP asked for (he can't change the xml)?